# Conditionally add in if condition to if statement if true

Tags: javascript, vue.js, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is it possible to conditionally add to an if statement? For example, I have this if statement `if (completed) { alert('Hello') }` I'm curious is it possible to add another condition to this ONLY if lastAssignment is true, for example `if (completed && extraCredit) { alert('Hello') }` Is it possible to add `&& extraCredit` to the if statement only if lastAssignment is true?

I've tried something like `if (completed && (lastAssignment ) ? extraCredit : '') { alert('Hello') }` but that doesn't seem to work like I want. I understand I could continue adding if statements within but I'm trying to see if there's an easier shorthand way of adding more conditions or as this grows it could be super long. Overall im using these conditions to return a list using filters incase anyone is curious.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Yes.  You can chain expressions.

Comment: Also `(completed && lastAssignment && extraCredit)` would be the same result, being false if the lastAssignment is false.

Comment: Oh thats good to know, thank you

Comment: @Zeus so your problem is solved?